# Image clipping with css issue

Tags: html, css, image, svg, png

My problem is that images disappears once I add the `clip` on it.

The image is positioned absolute and the parent element has relative position and height set to correct value.

I've tried on png and svg, but I need to get this done on svg images.

CSS pseudo:

```
.parent-element {
    position: relative;
    height: 240px;
}

img.my-img {
   clip: rect(0, 50px, 0, 50px);
   position: absolute;
}
```

I have also tried with  property instead and the same happens, the image just goes blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are not using clip correctly.  The first 0 shows where the top of your clipped area is and the 0 in the third position shows where the bottom is.  Setting both of these to 0 would leave you with no image. Try the following, and see if it works better.

```
clip: rect(0, 50px, 50px, 0);
```

Comment: Right, my assumptions about the parameters were wrong. Ended up with this one with my specific image: `clip: rect(0, 1128px, 240px, 50px)`.  The third parameter can not be 0